# Does deleting a variable before assigning it to another value solves any memory issues?

Tags: python, memory-management

I was going through a college assignment on KNN given in python and in that assignment there was one block of code where they delete X_train,Y_train,X_test and Y_test variables before assigning those variables to other data. And in the comments they added that it prevents memory issues.

```
 x = large_dataset
 del x
 x = another_large_datset   // block 1


 x = large_dataset
 x = another_large_datset // block 2
```

what would be the difference between the above two blocks of code.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
It appears that you merely need to look up how Python handles garbage collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples accomplish the same thing - they decrease the reference count of the value `"any_dataset"` by one. Using `del` does this explicitly, overwriting a variable does this implicitly. When a value has zero references to it, it will be garbage-collected *at some point in the future*.

This being the case, I can't see any "memory issues" being prevented by doing it one way or the other.

Further reading material:

- [Python `del` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969739/python-del-statement)
- [What happens to overwritten variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991456/what-happens-to-overwritten-variables-in-python)

Comment: if the data present in x is very large; will there be any effect on the process?

Comment: Like I said, both cases accomplish the exact same thing. If Python decides not to garbage-collect the old dataset before loading the new dataset, you *may* be strangled for memory, depending on your machine, the dataset size etc. But this does not depend on the examples in your question.